# Use of undefined constant wsq_CLASSES in WordPress with Security Questions plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I was using [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) with **WordPress** and it identified this code as problematic in WP [Security Questions](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/wp-security-questions/) plugin:

```
if ( ! defined( 'WSQ_VIEWS_PATH' ) ) {
    define( 'WSQ_VIEWS_PATH', wsq_CLASSES.'view' );
```

The error detected:

> Use of undefined constant `wsq_CLASSES` – assumed `wsq_CLASSES` (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

I am struggling to get any answers from the plugin author and I can't find any documentation about `wsq_CLASSES`. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Thanks.

Comment: It’s picking this up from the plugin code so really this is a question for the plugin developer, they’re the ones with not only the knowledge to fix it but they’re also the ones who *have* to do it so that it gets updated in the next release code :)

Comment: Since the developer isn't really responsive (according to your comments at least) then you'll need to find where this constant (or variable?) is declared and fix it to make it available to this part of the code so PHP stops complaining about it being undefined.

Comment: Ideally, after fixing this you should also notify the plugin developer about the fix so they can incorporate it into their code. That way, future updates (if any?) will correct this problem and you won't have to fix it again. Or just wait for the developer to respond and have them look into this for you.

Comment: @cabrerahector I downloaded the plugin folder onto my computer and used NotePad++ to search all files for both terms `WSQ_VIEWS_PATH` and `wsq_CLASSES` and they both only showed up in the two lines I stated already.

Comment: Then it's a bug within the plugin: the developer either removed the original declaration of these constants/variables from the plugin for some reason and forgot to update that part of the code, or maybe the plugin expects these constants to be defined on a different plugin for it to be able to use them (but doesn't check for the existence of the second constant, hence why I consider it to be a bug.) Seeing that both constants start with the *wsq_* prefix (*WordPress Security Questions*) I'm pretty sure it's the former.

Comment: @cabrerahector At the moment they are not responding to emails so I miht have to just comment out those two lines of code. Prefer not to but I have not found any other plugin that does what this one does. I prefer it fixed if poss.